# why onSensorChanged() method called without moving device

Tags: android, accelerometer

i am currently work on google place api with camera
when i open my app and move camera then my application shows me near by place that side my camera is open ......

its work perfect but my problame is whenever i move device or not onSensorChanged() is fire always and give me diffrent data from past...so its like my display addressed are continusly change its position

why onSensorChanged() is call when i dont move my device...its also change on when i put my mobile in table serface...that time also my onSensorChanged() called and its value is always diffrent

```
       @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            mAcceleromterReading =
                    SensorUtilities.filterSensors(event.values, mAcceleromterReading);
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mMagnetometerReading =
                    SensorUtilities.filterSensors(event.values, mMagnetometerReading);
            break;
    }
```

or can i do camera to near by place in other way ? give me suggestions

thanks in advance..

Comment: How large are the changes? If they're small, it's probably a combination of sensor noise and real vibrations that you can't perceive.

Comment: yes it is small means diffrance is 0.100 around

Comment: can i stop that ?

Comment: For my case, no they aren't smal,, they reach 8 m/s^2